# Is there a simple command for merging a topic branch by rebasing?

Tags: git

Starting from branch master, to merge a topic branch one just says

```
git merge topic
```

If one wants to rebase, however, the commands are

```
git rebase master topic
git checkout master
git merge topic
```

The last two lines just fast-forward the master branch to the topic branch, so variation is possible, e.g. I like the following pattern:

```
git rebase master topic
git rebase topic master
```

It gets even more complex when the state of the local "topic" branch shall be preserved:

```
git checkout -b tmp topic
git rebase master
git rebase tmp master
git branch -d tmp
```

Is there a simple command for that? Something that works as simple as git-merge on the CLI but actually performs a rebase, without moving the topic branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no perfect command that does this in one go, but there's a pretty close second.

Assuming that `topic` will cleanly fit atop `master` without conflict, this will work from the `master` branch:

```
git cherry-pick master..topic
```

`master..topic` is the set of changes in `topic` but not `master`, and cherry-picking them in order is effectively a rebase if `topic` is cleanly on `master`.

For the two-command perfect-fidelity case (or three to preserve `topic`), I wouldn't do two `rebase`s like you have there, I would do a `rebase` and an `update-ref` for clarity.

Comment: +1 Be very careful with the update-ref, though, especially if you're scripting this. You want to be sure that nothing went wrong and it really is a fast-forward.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely nothing built-in that does that. It's a complex enough sequence of actions that it's not really trivial to implement: what do you expect to happen the rebase fails?

In any case, if you don't mind doing wacky things like using rebase to effect a fast-forward, then you might prefer to do `git push . topic:master`, which will at least ensure that it's a fast-forward.

The best you can do is to alias/script it, so that `git merge-rebased master topic` means `git rebase master topic && git checkout master && git merge topic`, or whatever variation you prefer.